# Composer update not run

Tags: php, laravel, azure, docker, laravel-5

I have a problem when I run `composer update` for any project in laravel. It give me this error:
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires php ^7.1.3 but your php version (8.1.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - laravel/framework[v5.7.0, ..., 5.7.x-dev] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.1.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework 5.7.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.0, ..., 5.7.x-dev].
```

I tried to change it from composer.json  but still doesn't works
also I tried to `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` gives me other error which is :

```
Generating optimized autoload files
Class Egulias\EmailValidator\Exception\ExpectedQPair located in C:/laravel/job-portal-website-in-laravel-master/vendor/egulias/email-validator/EmailValidator\Exception\ExpectingQPair.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\laravel\job-portal-website-in-laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1204
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\laravel\job-portal-website-in-laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1215
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\laravel\job-portal-website-in-laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1227
Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\laravel\job-portal-website-in-laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1240
> @php artisan package:discover

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\laravel\job-portal-website-in-laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 1204

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\laravel\job-portal-website-in-laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 1215

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\laravel\job-portal-website-in-laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 1227

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\laravel\job-portal-website-in-laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 1240

Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in C:\laravel\job-portal-website-in-laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 833

Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in C:\laravel\job-portal-website-in-laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 907

Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in C:\laravel\job-portal-website-in-laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 833

Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in C:\laravel\job-portal-website-in-laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 907

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\laravel\job-portal-website-in-laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Config\Repository.php on line 141

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\laravel\job-portal-website-in-laravel-master\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Config\Repository.php on line 152

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute shou......ect.
```

so do you have idea how should I mage that error? can someone help???

Comment: looks like you have upgraded PHP to 8.1.0 but not checked that all your app code is compatible with it.

Comment: in fact I am trying to download code from git hub . but composer update doesnot work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !!
I used global composer with XAMPP server for php.

Answer (score 1):

Your php version is too high (8.1). Laravel 5.x is not compatible with php 8.
You have two options here:

1. [Upgrade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#updating-dependencies) your laravel installation (follow the guide until the 8.x version at least)
2. Downgrade your php version

Comment: how can  i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have upgraded your php version in your machine. So, to let your laravel application know that I have upgraded to newer version of php do following,

In you `root` directory open `composer.json` file and in `require` object there is php version mentioned. Change it to following.

```
"php": "7.1.3|8.0",
```

If this does not work then just use only current php version installed on your machine.

```
"php": "8.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case: my laravel 8.9

i try to use ^8.8

then run composer u

everything ok